# My computer freezes all the time and shows that the hard drive is spinning at 100%, what the hell is it doing?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, freeze, lag, acer-travelmate

I have a ACER travelmate laptop. I use it all the time and play games on it that I have installed. It is a fast computer but recently it keeps on freezing, getting slower, lagging, and slower frame rate. I have windows 7.

Comment: What are you doing when it becomes slow?  Is there a virus scanner that's started?

Comment: open resource monitor and look which programs cause a high HDD activity.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the most likely cause is a failing hard drive.

It is also worth taking 10 seconds to quickly rule out the possibility of the drive being nearly 100% full- something which can cause an increase in drive activity, and reduced responsiveness and system stability.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your harddrive may be dying.  See if you can find the "SMART" information off the hard drive which may confirm this - there are various free tools to do this depending on your OS.